# Variable is Not Available Using dbContexts?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, variables, linq-to-entities

I have the following code that throws an error on  the call for getOccupants within Using dbPC. Is there a way to make this value accessible in Using dbPC? Or a better way to accomplish this? I tried nesting Using dbPC inside of Using dbContext, but that also throws errors.

```
  Protected Sub btnPushSemester_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPushSemester.Click
    Dim dbPC As New Campus6Entities
    Dim dbContext As New pbu_housingEntities
    Using dbContext
        Dim get_Year = From p In dbContext.Configs _
                           Where p.Description = "year" _
                           Select p

        Dim get_Term = From p In dbContext.Configs _
                       Where p.Description = "term" _
                       Select p

        Dim thisYear = get_Year.First.textValue
        Dim thisTerm = get_Term.First.textValue
        Dim getOccupants = From p In dbContext.Residents _
                 Where p.semester = thisTerm _
                 Where p.year = thisYear _
                 Select p
    End Using
    Using dbPC
        For Each row In getOccupants
            Dim student_info = row
            Dim PCstudent = From r In dbPC.RESIDENCies _
                            Where student_info.people_code_id = r.PEOPLE_ID _
                            Where r.ACADEMIC_YEAR = thisYear _
                            Where r.ACADEMIC_TERM = thisTerm _
                            Select r

            For Each row2 In PCstudent
                Dim student_info2 = row2
                student_info2.DORM_BUILDING = student_info.Building1.building_code
                student_info2.DORM_ROOM = student_info.Room1.room1
                student_info2.RESIDENT_COMMUTER = "R"
                student_info2.DORM_CAMPUS = "O000000001"
                dbPC.SaveChanges()
            Next
        Next
    End Using

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `getOccupants` outside of the using block.  You can assign it inside the block, but you have to declare it outside or it goes out of scope before you actually need to use it.

Comment: When I do that I get the following error: "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection." It occurs on the line For Each row in getOccupants

Answer (score 1):

Because of deferred execution, the query is not actually executed until you iterate over the collection, but by that time, you have already disposed the dbContext object.  Try enclosing all the code in the Using blocks:

```
Using dbPC As New Campus6Entities
    Using dbContext As New pbu_housingEntities
        'rest of code here
    End Using
End Using
```